# Web Search API for Java

Tags: java, api, search

I need a Java library for doing web searches ( any search engine is good ).
I should be able to to write code such as:

```
WebSearch search = new WebSearch("Apple");
System.Out.Println("Results = " + search.Results.Count);
```

Does such a library/API exist ?

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/using_google_is_ajax_search_api_with_java.php) is your best options.

What is important here is Google's API:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?start=0&rsz=large&v=1.0&q=Apple
```

Note the "Apple" in the query String.

With this in mind, use any Java HttpClient (URLConnection class, Apache's HttpClient, you name it) to query and get results back.

Answer (score 1):

There's an API called JFreeWebSearch:
http://www.ke.tu-darmstadt.de/resources/jfreewebsearch

Answer (score -1):

[lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) is Java based search engine

Comment: can one use lucene to search the world wide web ?